# how to divide revenue between check_in_date and check_out_date, and turn those dates into single column named date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example of my dataset like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'check_in':['2020-02-27','2020-02-28'],'check_out':['2020-02-29','2020-03-02'],'revenue':[100,66]})
df

    check_in    check_out   revenue
0   2020-02-27  2020-02-29  100
1   2020-02-28  2020-03-02  66
```

and I want to turn it into something like this :

```
    date        revenue
0   2020-02-27  50
1   2020-02-28  72 
2   2020-02-29  22
2   2020-03-01  22
```

The `check_out` date is not included in the range; so the first period is 2 days (27 and 28) with 50 revenue each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method to solve this is first get difference between the out and in dates and then add the difference as Timedelta, . Then use the len of the range to divide the revenue to split and then groupby with sum

---

**Solution:**

```
a = df['check_out'].sub(df['check_in']).dt.days
b = a.map(range) #range automatically excludes the last entry
c = df['check_in'].add(pd.to_timedelta(b.explode(),unit='days'))

out = (c.to_frame('date').assign(revenue=df['revenue'].div(a))
       .groupby("date")['revenue'].sum().reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

        date  revenue
0 2020-02-27     50.0
1 2020-02-28     72.0
2 2020-02-29     22.0
3 2020-03-01     22.0
```

---

Considering your actual columns are datetime (*if not you can convert then using below*)

```
df[['check_in','check_out']] = df[['check_in','check_out']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best answer so far, even though I have to make some adjustment to the original datasets.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to split the revenue equally per day in the range (excluding the "check_out" day), and calculate the sum of revenues per day.

You can use `pandas.date_range` and `explode` to create the revenue per day (with the help of temporary helper columns), then `groupby`+`sum`:

```
(df.assign(check_out=pd.to_datetime(df['check_out'])-pd.Timedelta('1D'),
           date=lambda d: d.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r['check_in'], r['check_out']), axis=1),
           n=lambda d: d['date'].apply(len)
          )
   .explode('date')                                # get 1 line per day
   .assign(revenue=lambda d: d['revenue']/d['n'])  # split the revenue equally
   .groupby('date')['revenue'].sum()               # sum the same days
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
        date  revenue
0 2020-02-27     50.0
1 2020-02-28     72.0
2 2020-02-29     22.0
3 2020-03-01     22.0
```